# Optimizing a function of argmax

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

The function $f(\mathbf{x})$ is defined as follows:

$$f(\mathbf{x}) = \arg \max_y g(\mathbf{x}, y)$$

In other words, to evaluate the function $f$ for a given $\mathbf{x}$, we need to solve an optimization problem. The function $g(\mathbf{x},y)$ is concave in $y$ for a fixed value of $\mathbf{x}$, but there is no closed-form expression available for the solution of this concave problem. Furthermore, $g(\mathbf{x},y)$ is not concave in $\mathbf{x}$ for a fixed $y$.

My question is this: I wish to optimize the function $f(\mathbf{x})$; how would I do this? For instance, is it correct to state that $$\mathrm{arg.}\underset{x}{\mathrm{max}}f(\mathbf{x})=\mathrm{arg.}\underset{x,y}{\mathrm{max}}\ g(\mathbf{x},y)$$

So in that case would maximizing $f(\mathbf{x})$ be equivalent to the following optimization problem:

$$\mathrm{\underset{\mathbf{x},y}{maximize}}\quad g(\mathbf{x},y)$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any guarantees that these maxima exist? Also, are there any continuity assumptions on $g$?

Comment: Yes, both $f$ and $g$ are bounded above and continuous (although $g$ is piecewise linear, so not smooth). So the maxima do exist.

Comment: If the arg max of g(x,y) for a fixed x isn't unique, then you will have issues.

Comment: `\arg \max`, please.

Comment: The argmax may be set-valued. You need to tell us what you mean by maximizing a set-valued function.

Comment: @ Pete Caradonna and Brian Borchers: The function g is concave with respect to y and additionally has a unique argmax for a given x. So it is not set-valued.

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumptions of smoothness...
The equality is not always verified.

If you consider a function of two variables and you optimize wrt each variable sequencelly, then the solution may be different from the solution when considering the two variables at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your insight @Reda. Then how would one go about trying to maximize $f(\mathbf{x})$?

Comment: Optimizing the variables together is the best choice.